# This error code applies only to merchants on FDC Omaha. The value submitted in the merchant number field is invalid

Tags: payment-gateway, authorize.net, merchant-account

I configured my Authorize.Net account to get payments from clients on my site using CIM API. When a client get registered on my site, he creates his payment profile. All the  information are stored on authorize.net. I save only profile id to get payments. After completion of one month, I get payment by sending request to Authorize.Net.

Every thing is going fine, and I get payment. But against some profiles, there is some issue, i get error

> Response Reason Code: 205 Response Reason Text: This transaction has
>   been declined. Other Suggestions: This error code applies only to
>   merchants on FDC Omaha.  The value submitted in the  merchant number
>   field is invalid.

Is it some programming issue or some thing else? I searched this on authorize.net but could not find proper solution. I am unable to understand what is `merchant number field`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Authorize.Net Developer Community Forums](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Error-response-2-205/td-p/694)

> A call to Authorize.net and a response to a support ticket both said
>   that the merchant service provider (MSP) had set the status of the
>   merchant account to inactive. So we contacted the MSP and obtained a
>   Processor Configuration Sheet or the VAR sheet, which contained all
>   the necessary bits of information to activate the account. Then we
>   called Authorize.net again and they resolved the issue over the phone,
>   and conducted a test with us in real time.